# How do I make a command line always show in front of another app

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, powershell

let's say I only have one monitor and I open an IDE and a powershell window. I need to type words in the IDE's current tab while watching the conent of the command line.

[image]

The problem I have is, everytime I work on the IDE, then the IDE will be the main process thefore completed cover the command prompt. I have to click the command prompt window in the taskbar to bring it back or I have to resize both IDE and comand prompt so they both takes up 50/50 space of the screen, which is something I don't want

so is it a tool that I can use to make a command prompt always show in front of another app, pretty much like CSS's Z index, so the command prompt always has the highest z value

Comment: Specifically in VS Code's case, you can run a PowerShell terminal inside the application window, and so it coexists beside the code you're working on.

Comment: Also, please note that questions specifically asking us to recommend software or hardware to solve a problem are off topic. Please read the HELP section to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Windows Terminal to run powershell, it has an Always On Top feature. Or you could use the ["Always on Top" powertoys utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/always-on-top) to give that functionality to any window.

```
For Windows Terminal
```

Right click on the title bar and chose `Settings`. Navigate in the menu to `Appearance` and there look for `Always on top`, which you then can enable.

Comment: Could you explain how to find and enable that Always On Top function in Terminal?

Comment: @music2myear Edited to add that information.